# Loadbalancer IP/External IP is not getting generated on GKE cluster after using traefik Ingress controller

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

When I try to setup traefik ingress controller on GKE, loadBalancer IP is not getting created on GCP to access the application externally though by looking on traefik dashboard, internal traefik IP is assigned successfully. Please find the traefik ingress YAML file for your reference:-

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
annotations:
   kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
   traefik.frontend.passHostHeader: "false"
   traefik.frontend.rule.type: PathPrefixStrip
creationTimestamp: 2018-05-03T10:51:44Z
generation: 3
name: cheese
namespace: traefik-poc
resourceVersion: "1120714"
selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/traefik- 
poc/ingresses/cheese
uid: f831bbee-4ebf-11e8-9163-42010a8401fe
spec:
  rules:
  - host: traefik-poc.example.com
  http:
  paths:
  - backend:
      serviceName: stilton
      servicePort: http
    path: /stilton
  - backend:
      serviceName: cheddar
      servicePort: http
    path: /cheddar
  - backend:
      serviceName: wensleydale
      servicePort: http
    path: /wensleydale
status:
   loadBalancer: {}
```

Can anyone help me on this if possible and let me know if you need any further details to debug this issue.

Comment: Assuming ingress controller is working fine, can you share your deployment and the service (the ones from your app)?